# Sobrepasar tamaño en el eje y en ng2-charts en Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, chart.js, charts

estoy trabajando con `ng2-charts` en `angular 2`, el detalle es que el valor de referencia de las barras sobrepasa el limite del `eje Y` , lo cual en valor no logra apreciarse bien.

Habrá forma de que la barras no lleguen al limite del eje Y?

[Aqui el link de la libreria de Charts Demo - Angular](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#/BarChart)

Como se aprecia en la imagen no se logra ver el número 2.

[image: Gráfico generado con ng2-charts]

Mi archivo `.ts`

```
import { ChartDataSets, ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import * as pluginDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss'],
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    
    scales: { xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          suggestedMin: 0
        }
      }], 
    yAxes: [{}] },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end',
      }
    }
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Mujeres', 'Varones'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [0, 0], label: 'Actualizado' },
    { data: [2, 2], label: 'No actualizado' }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  
  public chartClicked({ event, active }: { event: MouseEvent, active: {}[] }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

  public chartHovered({ event, active }: { event: MouseEvent, active: {}[] }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }

}
```

mi `.html`

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        [chartType]="barChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Yo estuve con eso liado y probé de muchas maneras diferentes, la única solución aceptable fue poner la leyenda debajo de la gráfica.

legend: {
display: true,
position: 'bottom',
}

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Lo anotado parece más bien un comentario que una respuesta. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer]